# Avada after URL has changed Design/Fonts/Logo not set

Tags: wordpress

we had a WordPress installation set up under a subdomain: new.test.com.
After we were done with the setup, we moved everything to a new domain, [www.test.de](http://www.test.de).
In the process, we also replaced every URL in the database and cleared Avada's cache accordingly.

But now we have the problem that no logo is displayed anymore, the fonts are not correct and also ICONS not.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: try to change the permalink blank to post type

Comment: where can I find this?

Comment: Under the setting, you find the permalinks (http://prntscr.com/18pwxut). First, select plain and save after change to post name and save.

Comment: Still same. Cleared cache from avada too

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache inside of avada theme options will clear all settings to default.

You removed all settings, as avadas theme-cache is not a browser cache.
It stores your settings in your DB.
Clearing this, removes your settings.

There is no way back without a backup.

You need to activate a backup and download the settings-file in avada theme (options -> import/export) so you can restore your settings later in the theme options if anything goes wrong.